# Marshalling c# arrays to pointers for static c library

Tags: c#, pointers, marshalling, static-libraries, zlib

i am still struggling on calling some functions out of a c static library.
I wrote a wrapper after this [toms wrapper](http://tom-shelton.net/index.php/2008/12/11/creating-a-managed-wrapper-for-a-lib-file/) with visual studio around the static lib and can now access the functions on the c# side, but i get some errors when dealing with them.

So here is what the function looks original:

```
ZEXTERN Int32 ZEXPORT compressZIP OF((unsigned char *dest,   Uint32 destLen,
                             unsigned char *source, Uint32 sourceLen,
                             Uint32 *_crc32));
```

which resulted on the c# side to

```
public int compressZIP(byte* dest, uint destLen, byte* source, uint sourceLen,
                            uint* _crc32);
```

So, now i am stuck on the pointer issues, i tried stuff out like

```
byte[] data = new byte[size]
(fixed ptr = data)
```

and pass the ptrs into the function. but i always end up with some memory violations or other memory exceptions at all.

When i call the uncompressZIP wich looks kinda the same, i get 2 characters correct uncompressed but then only fence stuff.

Can someone help me filling the correct arguments to the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare it as a pointer on C# side, but as a byte array. And be sure to include the [OutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute.aspx).

A working example:

```
[DllImport("PixelFlowIE.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "PixelFlow")]
private static extern void PixelFlowDLL([In, Out] Node[] gi, int width, int height, SourceInfo[] sources, int sourceCount, int iterations, int iterPerPeriod, ProgressCallback prg);
```

Comment: but anyways the problem seems to be on the c side